A one-off calculation of the maximum distance between an orthogonal regression line and the data points
Instead of finding the distance for each point separately and selecting the largest, is there another way to calculate this distance once, or to find a point with the largest distance/error at the stage of calculating $\bar{x}$, $\bar{y}$, $s_{xx}$, $s_{xy}$ and $s_{yy}$, when the line of best fit is not yet known?
$$\bar{x}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nx_i$$
$$\bar{y}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^ny_i$$
$$s_{xx}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\bar{x})^2$$
$$s_{xy}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\bar{x})(y_i-\bar{y})$$
$$s_{yy}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n(y_i-\bar{y})^2$$
Best fit line $y=mx+b$ coefficients:
$$m=\frac{s_{yy}-s_{xx}+\sqrt{(s_{yy}-s_{xx})^2+4s^2_{xy}}}{2s_{xy}}$$
$$b=\bar{y}-m\bar{x}$$
The distance $\rho$ from the line of best fit to each point is:
$$\rho=\frac{\lvert b+mx_i-y_i\rvert}{\sqrt{1+m^2}}$$
Is it possible to say which point would be at the greatest distance from line, or what the maximum distance would be without calculating the distance for each point separately?
P. S. In general, I need this to reduce the load and speed up the calculations in the software implementation, but the question is more related to mathematics than to programming.

Hi Bruce! You are looking for outlier detection I guess.

@YvesDaoust It is a line of best fit y = mx + b for a two-dimensional data set according to orthogonal regression.

@m-stgt Thank you, that's a very interesting method, although it's even more complicated than simply calculating the distance for each point. Frankly, I hope that the x̄, ȳ, Sxx, Sxy and Syy calculated for the line of best fit, and perhaps the dataset itself, can somehow be used to "predict" the point with the greatest distance, or a one-off calculation of that distance.

@YvesDaoust -- Where is ordinary regression shown here, and how should "orthogonal" regression look like according to your knowledge?

@YvesDaoust See this link

Just suppose it is never vertical. And I didn't downvote your answer.

@Bruce -- I see no other way than to have a look at every individual point $(x_i, y_i)$. But to find the most distant one you don't need its true distance. Since $\displaystyle \sqrt{1+m^2}$ is constant for the current calculation you may omit it, at least for the "hunt". HTH

@m-stgt I agree with you, I just stopped at finding the largest result of the expression $\lvert mx_i-y_i\rvert$ for each point - this should be enough to find the maximum distance. Unfortunately, the performance gain is negligible because these calculations are performed many times in a nested loop.

Your question is not to find "the top outlier" but to identify the most distant point $(x_i, y_i)$ before computing the line of best fit. For this I estimate a similar calculation effort as taking the "detour" and get the line of best fit first.
To find the most distant point you do not need its true orthogonal distance $\displaystyle\rho_i=\frac{\lvert b+mx_i-y_i\rvert}{\sqrt{1+m^2}}$, comparing relative displacement $\displaystyle r_i=\lvert b+mx_i-y_i\rvert$ woud work too since $\sqrt{1+m^2}$ is constant for the current case.
BTW, what you show how to compute $s_{xx}$, $s_{xy}$ and $s_{yy}$ is correct but looks too laborious IMO because you have to determine $\bar{x}$ and $\bar{y}$ in advance. To loop once only over all $n$ points I'd suggest to sum $x,\ x^2,\ y,\ y^2$, and $xy$ like several ancient pocket calculators did (and still do) with the $\sum +$ key. Those sums and $n$ are enough to compute YX-, XY- and Orthogonal Regression as I once showed here -- if this link does not work for you also there: http://hp41.org/html/LR3K.html.
An additional benefit using a. m. sums is, eliminating a single pair of values does not require to repeat the summing drudgery for the remaining $n-1$ points, a simple correction of the present sums is sufficing.
Addendum – formulas using sums of $x,\ x^2,\ y,\ y^2$, and $xy$ only:
First, the model for the LS method: $y=mx+b\tag{1}$
Next, $m$ by regression of y on x, the formula pocket calculators use for Linear Regression (see HP10C Usr Mnl, p. 95, p 97 of the PDF):
Note, in following formulas $\sum$ stands for $\sum_{k=1}^n$, $x$ for $x_k$, and $y$ for $y_k$.
$$m_{(YX)}=\frac{\displaystyle n\sum xy-\sum x\cdot\sum y}{\displaystyle n\sum x^2-\left(\sum x\right)^2}\tag{2}$$
An intermediate value:$z=\frac{\displaystyle n\sum y^2-\left(\sum y\right)^2}{\displaystyle n\sum x^2-\left(\sum x\right)^2}-1\tag{3}$
$m$ for Orthogonal Regression with $(2)$ and $(3)$:
$$m_{(ortho)}=\frac{\displaystyle z+\sqrt{z^2+(2m_{(YX)})^2}}{2m_{(YX)}}\tag{4}$$
Ordinate intercept $b$ for both a. m. cases, use corresponding $m$ from $(2)$ or $(4)$:$$b=\displaystyle\frac{-m\sum x+\sum y}{n}=\bar{y}-m\bar{x}\tag{5}$$
This formulas are for typical scenarios and fail for pathological cases (which I consider as intentional sabotage).

To whom it may concern: downvoting without explanation is cowardly IMO. At least a hint or a better answer would be fair.

Thank you for identifying areas for improvement. I will implement the recommended changes. However, I am experiencing difficulty in obtaining the expressions for $m$ and $b$ using sums of $x,\ x^2,\ y,\ y^2$, and $xy$ even after thoroughly reviewing your article. I would be grateful if you could help me with this.

Also, I can identify a line as vertical ($s_{xy}=0,s_{xx}<s_{yy}$), horizontal ($s_{xy}=0,s_{xx}>s_{yy}$) or indeterminate ($s_{xy}=0,s_{xx}=s_{yy}$) using $s_{xx}, s_{xy}$ and $s_{yy}$, but how would it work in your case?

@Bruce -- If $s_{xy}=0$ also the correlation coefficient of your "dot cloud" is null, therefore $y=mx+b$ the wrong model.

No, it's not. Thank you for explaining the formulas! However, I think you missed the square for $z$ under the square root in the expression for $m_{(ortho)}$. It must be $m_{(ortho)}=\frac{z+\sqrt{z^2+(2m_{(YX)})^2}}{2m_{(YX)}}$

@Bruce -- TY for finding an error, corrected. BTW, I would be highly interested in examples with $s_{xy}=0$.
